# GitHub/GitLab REST API - How to know a branch (dev) is merged into another branch (master) or not?

Tags: git, rest, api

Does GitHub or GitLab support a REST API to let us know that a branch (Ex: develop) is merged into another branch (Ex: master) or not?

If yes, API will return the detail information of that merge.

Comment: Git itself doesn't have a REST API. Do you mean GitHub?

Comment: Yes, I mean GitHub or GitLab REST API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GitLab REST API, we saw there is an API to get all merge requests. We don't see similar API for GitHub REST API.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests

curl -XGET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/6888/merge_requests?target_branch=master"

Answer (score 1):

I see you have edited the question to include `REST API`. git doesn't have any REST API. You must be confusing it with SCM tool like Github or Gitlab?

---

You can use [`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) to find the latest common commit between two branches.

- If merge-base doesn't return any commit, then the branches have not been merged.
- If there exists a common commit and development HEAD point to same commit, then `dev` branch is completely merged into `master` and there are no new commits after the merge.
- If there exists a common commit and it is not same as current HEAD of the `dev` branch, then `dev` branch has been merged into `master` branch previously and also has new commits since the merge.

Comment: Hi Shashank, does GIT support an API to do this? We are building a tool that talks with Git through API so Git command is not a solution for us.

Comment: @TonyTran, git is just a revision control system. By itself it doesn't have any REST API. Do you mean API of git hosting service like Github/Gitlab etc?

Comment: @TonyTran : git does not have a REST API. Github does.

Comment: Yes, I mean GitHub or GitLab REST API, do they support API to support this question?

Comment: Which one specifically? Have you checked their documentation?